# How to RedirectToAction with a model passed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an model class that is used to validate some user input.

I have an controller with the following.

```
public IActionResult Checkout(GiftCard giftCard)
{
}
```

I was wondering how I could on an different action redirect it back to it such as

```
public IActionResult Preview(GiftCard giftCard)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Checkout");
}
```

The above doesn't work because asp.net is trying to find an action without the model like the one below

```
public IActionResult Checkout()
{
}
```

Comment: You cannot 'hide' the query string values (if they are not there, then the values would not be passed to the `Checkout()` method. You should be persisting the object (e.g. in a database) and passing its `ID` value so that it can be retrieved again in the GET method (an option is to use `TempData` but if the user were to refresh the browser, then it will fail)

Comment: Is your example complete because I do not see what you want to do?
Why to redirect to Checkout action from Preview action and not directly send your model to Checkout action in your razor view ?

Answer (score 0):

if your url going to be really long make a shorturl so load that and redirect from there, if you use ajax it wont be visible

Answer (score 0):

You could use action with another name and apply action selector to your renamed method. Like next:

```
[ActionName("Checkout")]
[HttpPost] //Recomend you send user input via post
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] // and use validation token
public IActionResult CheckoutConfirmed(GiftCard giftCard)
{
    //your code
}
public IActionResult Checkout()
{
    //your code
}
```

- Check out more about [ASP.NET MVC - Selectors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_selectors.htm)
- If you need more information about [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), you could find it there - [Chapter 12: Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404095.aspx)
- And also, you could find great article about posting there - [ASP.NET MVC Preview 5 and Form Posting Scenarios](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` has a second parameter called `routeValues` with which you can pass the `GiftCard` like following.

```
public IActionResult Preview(GiftCard giftCard)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Checkout", giftCard);
}
```